# Swift: static String variable in a struct becomes chinese characters

Tags: swift, struct, character, keychain, static-variables

The code in my Keychain class:

```
struct Keys {
    static var token: String = "MyAppToken"
    ...
}

internal class func set(key: String, value: String) -> Bool {
    if let data = value.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding) {
        return set(key, value: data)
    }

    return false
}

internal class func get(key: String) -> NSString? {
    if let data = getData(key) {
        return NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
    }

    return nil
}

...
```

In unit test doing something like this works without any issues:

```
func testKeychain() {
    let setKey = Keychain.set(Keychain.Keys.token, value: "test")
    let getKey = Keychain.get(Keychain.Keys.token)

    XCTAssertTrue(setKey, "set keychain value with string")
    XCTAssertNotNil(getKey, "retrieve keychain value with key: \(Keychain.Keys.token)")
    XCTAssertTrue(getKey!.isEqualToString("test"), "retrieved keychain value matches raw string")
}
```

In the live code, when I save the value the same way as in the test, everything looks ok. But when trying to retrieve the token the parameter `Keychain.Keys.token` becomes Chinese characters (except for the last character!?! -> "慐杩湡潔敫n" instead of "MyAppToken"). This causes the `get(Keychain.Keys.token)` call to return `nil`. How can something like this happen?

**Edit:**
This only happens in the "release" build configuration. So, I guess it has something to do with the build settings.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently this issue was caused by the Swift Compiler Optimization. Turning the Optimization Level to "none" has solved it.